# generic URL Rewrites and 301 Redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I wrote apache mod_rewrite with proxy

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/birthday-bengaluru  $1/birthday/bengaluru [R,P,NC]
```

if I want to do one more city like Newyork again want to write one more line like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/birthday-newyork  $1/birthday/Newyork [R,P,NC]
```

is it anyway we can write like this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/birthday-(.*)$  $1/birthday/$1 [R,P,NC]
```

thanks
Mahesha M

Comment: What exactly is the question and why are you using `R` and `P` flags together?

Comment: the new url has to stay and its going to call internally old one, www.example.com/birthday-bengaluru is going to call www.example.com/birthday/bengaluru and its stay first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a small type in your redirect. From the RewriteRule, you can access the content of the first bracket with $1 and the content of the second bracket with $2 (and so on). You are using two times $1 in your rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)/birthday-(.*)$  $1/birthday/$1 [R,P,NC]`, so this would make a redirect from

`http://domain.com/birthday-bengaluru`
to
`http://domain.com/birthday-http://domain.com/birthday`

The rewrite rule should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/birthday-(.*)$  $1/birthday/$2 [R,P,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this RewriteRule ^(.*)/birthday-(.*)$  $1/birthday/$2 [R,P,NC], its not working :(

Comment: Just to be clear, does your first rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)/birthday-bengaluru  $1/birthday/bengaluru [R,P,NC]` work, when you try to open `/birthday-bengaluru` ?

Comment: Thanks, your first solution is working, did some apache syntax mistakes